# Returning the error why mail failed to send within Yii 2's base mailer class

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

I'm using `Yii 2` and am using the mailer from the [base mailer class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mail-basemailer.html) and for the most part it is working fine, but sometimes it fails to send..... so my code is like:

```
// Let's start composing the message
$mail = Yii::$app->mailer->compose($view_data, $view_params);

//.........

// Send the message
$send = $mail->send();
```

Sometimes `$send` is `false` but I'm not sure how you find out WHY it is false? Is there a way to get the error that made it become false?

Comment: @AresDraguna - I would prefer to get the error so I can pass it to my own logs.

Comment: Yii2 comes with some REALLY good logs man. I mean top notch logs. you can view them in your browser if you have debugging mode on or in runtime/logs or /debug you don't need separate logs, but if you insist on that, I cannot help you, sorry... I don't know how to do that...

Comment: Hey buddy, I think `afterSend()` would be a useful method for you. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mail-basemailer.html#afterSend()-detail . As you have logs.

Comment: @AresDraguna That's exactly what I am using. Yii's logging tools; but I need to be able to find the error so I can use `Yii::error()` with the actual error :)

Comment: @AliMasudianPour I had a look at that method, but I'm not sure how it would help me as I still am unsure how to get the actual error from the mailer to log.

Comment: Look at Yii's logs to see the error. You can log it differently afterwards but to begin with looking at the logs. Do you mean there is no error shown in there? Also I do not think it is a good idea for the script to wait for the email to be sent. I would build a cron job to send the actual emails from a list. It can try multiple times before it fails.

Comment: @MihaiP. Which logs exactly? I have custom log files setup for all the log types.

Comment: Do you use `useFileTransport = true` in config?

Comment: You can on to `info` log and get `Yii::info('Sending email "' . $message->getSubject() . '" to "' . $address . '"', __METHOD__);` in your `app.log`. Use https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/mail/BaseMailer.php#L239 for `var_dump($isSuccessful)` ^_^

Comment: @EvgeniyTkachenko Nope, it's set to `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sending multiple recipients message, you should check for failures : http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#getting-failures-by-reference, e.g. :

```
if (Yii::$app->mailer->getSwiftMailer()->send($message->getSwiftMessage(), $failures))    
{
    // do what you want with $failures var
}
```

And if you really want to handle smtp errors in your yii app, you should use swiftmailer logger plugin : http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html#logger-plugin

PS : first I would check yii and smtp logs to see what kind of errors occurs...

Comment: Thanks. So I guess if I wanted to use that logger I would probably have to extend the Yii swiftmailer class then? Also, as for Yii's logs - not getting anything about the failure in my error logs, unsure where to check the smtp logs. I suspect the issue may be a timeout issue though as it's on my local env and I have noticed it takes a few seconds to send mail.

Comment: You could extend Yii mailer, or simply use directly swiftmailer.

Comment: And how can I do this with `yii\symfonymailer` ?