# How to get error message from yii2 symfonymailer

Tags: php, email, yii2, symfony-mailer

I am using Yii2 to send e-mails using [yii2-symfonymailer](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-symfonymailer).

And in case of errors it returns `false` from the `send()` method, so I can check if sendind was successfull.

My question is:
**How can I get the error messages, when send fails?**

This is the code for sending.

```
$message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
    ->setFrom('from@domain.com')
    ->setTo('to@domain.com')
    ->setSubject('Message subject')
    ->setTextBody('Plain text content')
    ->setHtmlBody('<b>HTML content</b>');

if (!$message->send()) {
  // handle the errors
}
```

For debugging I need a way either to get an exception with the error info from the send() method like in php mailer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2386576/2377961).

Or a way to "ask" the mailer about the "lastErrors", e.g. like this:

```
if (!$message->send()) {
  echo "Could not send: " . Yii::$app->mailer->getLastError();
}
```

I found similar question for another yii2 mailer (see [Returning error within Yii 2's base mailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545079/returning-the-error-why-mail-failed-to-send-within-yii-2s-base-mailer-class) ).

But this works not for my mailer, and changing the mailer is no option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in trying to get last error from mailer when `$message->send()` return `false`.

When you are using yii2-symfonymailer `$message->send()` will never return false when sending fails in mailer itself. It will return `true` on success or throw exception on failure.

See [`sendMessage()` function implementation in mailer](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-symfonymailer/blob/41f33dd9e7c0c5c6e9b3bd349a93ad0223b88e74/src/Mailer.php#L181).

The only case when the `$message->send()` method will return `false` is when `beforeSend()` callback returns `false`. And that will only happen if something sets [`yii\mail\MailEvent::$isValid`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-mail-mailevent) property to false during [`yii\mail\BaseMailer::EVENT_BEFORE_SEND`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-mail-basemailer#EVENT_BEFORE_SEND-detail) event.

Comment: Ahhh, great that is what I needed.
It seems that we still have an older version of the mailer, what does NOT throw anything.

So upgrading themailer should sove this issue, thank you.

I accept your answer, when I coul test this

Comment: The update to a newer version solved the problem.

Important upgrade note:

When you upgrade to the version with eceptions from a version, that does not have it, than the "afterSend" Method is NOT called, when an exception is fired